# Multidimensional hyperparameter search with vw-hypersearch in Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit, hyperparameters

[vw-hypersearch](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/utl/vw-hypersearch) is the Vowpal Wabbit wrapper intended to optimize hyperparameters in vw models: regularization rates, learning rates and decays, minibatches, bootstrap sizes etc. In the [tutorial](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Using-vw-hypersearch) for vw-hypersearch there is a following example:

```
vw-hypersearch  1e-10  5e-4  vw  --l1 %  train.dat
```

Here `%` means the parameter to be optimized, `1e-10  5e-4` are the lower and upper bounds for the interval over which to search. The library uses [golden section search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search) method to minimize the number of iterations.

But what if I want to search over multiple hyperparameters? From the sources like [this](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/738) github issue discussion, I get a hint that possibly no multidimentional search methods are realized in vw. Thus, the only way out is to write one's own task-specific optimizers. Am I right?

Comment: 1) Yes, you're right.  2) You could write your own or Ideally, contribute to this open-source project along the lines of the discussion you linked to, so everyone can benefit.

Comment: See https://github.com/martinpopel/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/vw-hyperopt-plans as an inspiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now this can be done with the module `vw-hyperopt.py` that lives at `/vowpal_wabbit/utl/` in the repository.

See my pull-request here: https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/pull/867

In the near future this will be better documented.