# Get holdout loss in Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit, hyperparameters

I'm trying to implement grid search or more sophisticated hyperparameter search in Vowpal Wabbit. Is there a relatively simple way to get a loss function value obtained on a validation set (holdout in vw) for this purpose? VW must have computed it e.g. for every number of passes, because early stopping happens depending on it's value.

As yet, I detour this by creating a separate file with validation dataset, saving different models' predictions on this dataset, and comparing their performance in python, thereby incurring unnecessary waste of data. But maybe there is a way to use vw holdout scores explicitly?

Comment: See `--holdout_after` (and `vw -h | grep holdout`). That said, I also usually prepare a separate validation set, so I can compare models trained on different training sizes and plot the learning curve. I also compute the train loss (train error) to assess the amount of overfitting. I can provide some scripts.

Comment: Thank you! I would be very grateful if you share the scripts for learning curves. Do they compute progressive loss at each training step? As for holdout, I tried to use `--holdout_after` but I don't know how to get loss out of it, or to save predictions for holdout set after each pass. It seems like vw `-p` flag when learning means saving predictions on train set, not on holdout one.

Comment: See https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/pull/841 (my other scripts are too specific for my own experimental setting, that is not useful for anyone else)

Comment: See also https://github.com/martinpopel/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/vw-hyperopt-plans (I don't have time to implement `vw-hyperopt` now, though I would like to do so in future. At least my plans may be a source of inspiration.)

Comment: With `--holdout_after=N` you need to concatenate the train file and the holdout file and compute N = the number of examples in the train file. The loss reported by VW after the first pass will be marked with `h` (as holdout) and it will be based on your holdout data. If you use `-p` in addition, you will save the predictions (on the whole concatenated file).

Comment: Instead of `--holdout_after`, you can use `--save_per_pass` and evaluate the models saved after each pass with `vw -t -i model123 -d test.file`. Another alternative is to save the model with `--save_resume` after each pass (or another chunk of training data) and continue training as needed and interweave training with testing (but loading the models into memory takes some time). Yet another option is to save the model on demand (perhaps with `vw --daemon`) using https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Input-format#on-demand-model-saving

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'll try out `vw-experiment`. So far, I managed to make a python wrapper doing golden ratio search on multiple dimensions (a straightforward extension of `vw-hypersearch`), but it seems to take almost the same number of steps to converge as the full grid search, not finding the global minimum anyway.

Comment: I was also thinking about using `hyperopt` or `bayesopt` for VW, and I would be very happy if I succeed and contribute something to the project. @arielf suggested that I do it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242742/multidimensional-hyperparameter-search-with-vw-hypersearch-in-vowpal-wabbit). But I have never dealt with perl, the only language I'm currently familiar with is python. Is it fatal? I think the most computational burden will lie on VW, so python wrappers will not slow down the things much.

Comment: So, if I use random holdout, will VW save predictions on holdout observations and train observations indistinguishably to the same file?

Comment: I noticed that when using multiple passes, VW saves predictions for each  observation multiple times. So, am I right that if I use `holdout_after=N`, the correct way to get holdout loss is just to pick up the _last pass_ holdout predictions from the `-p` file?

Comment: What do you mean by "random holdout"? By default each 10th example is holdout. With `--holdout_after` the end of file is the holdout set. So it is never random. The `-p` prediction file contains always the same number of lines as the input file times number of passes.

Comment: Ok, thank you. For some reason I believed that by default it takes 1/10 at random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments, there are several ways how to get holdout loss from VW (they can be combined):

1. With one-pass learning, VW reports progressive validation loss, which (simply said) converges approximately to the same value as holdout loss after enough examples.
2. With multiple passes, VW reports holdout loss (unless `--holdout_off` is specified) based on **each** 10th example (not on random 1/10 of examples). Using `--holdout_period` one can specify different number than 10.
3. Parameter `--holdout_after=N` specifies that first N examples of the input data will be used for training and the rest of the file as holdout set (instead each 10th example).
4. One can use `-p predictions.txt` and compute the loss outside of VW (by comparing `predictions.txt` with the input data with gold labels). When X passes are used, `predictions.txt` will contain X*number_of_input_data_examples. Thus, it is recommended to train on the training data (possibly with multiple passes), save the model to a file and then use VW only to predict: `vw -i trained.model -t -d test.input -p test.predictions`.
5. In some scenarios `--save_per_pass` or `vw --daemon` and [saving model on demand](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Input-format#on-demand-model-saving) may be helpful.
6. For computing both holdout(test) loss and train loss, comfortably from the command line, one can use [vw-experiment](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/utl/vw-experiment).